# Requests: "params" keyword not working properly?

Tags: python, github, python-requests

I am trying to make a request to GitHub API using the "params" keyword:

```
import requests

parameters = {'language': 'python', 'sort': 'stars'}

url = 'https://api.github.com/search/repositories' #?language:python&sort=stars

response = requests.get(url, params=parameters) 
print(response.url)
response_dict = response.json()

items_list = response_dict['items']

for item in items_list:
    print(item['name'])
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "github.py", line 10, in <module>
    items_list = response_dict['items']
KeyError: 'items'
```

However, the very same code works fine if I skip the params method and just assign whole URL to the variable. By printing the URL for both mehods I noticed that using "params" omits the "q=" part in the URL. Could it be the reason of the error, and if so, how do I fix it?

Comment: Yes, it is the reason. `q` is mandatory. Where do you specify the `q` parameter? It looks like you haven't included that in `parameters` dict.

Comment: You're probably getting an error from the API. Check the response status code `response.status_code` Just try printing the `response_dict` to see the error code.

Comment: I don't specify the 'q' parameter (the code I posted is all the code I got). Should I put it into the dictionary somehow? Also, response status code is 422.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Documentation on [`Search API`](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/#search-based-on-the-main-language-of-a-repository) states that you can specify fields including `language` separated by `:` in the querystring parameter `q` like follows:

```
import requests

parameters = {"q": "language:python", "sort": "stars"}
url = "https://api.github.com/search/repositories"

response = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
response.raise_for_status()
response_dict = response.json()

for item in response_dict["items"]:
    print(item["name"])
```

You can check out the [documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/searching-repositories/) to find out what else you can add into `q`.